# How do I search for a specific file type using PHP's glob function?

Tags: php, database, search, glob, scandir

So, my attempt at searching for a .wav sound file in my database using PHP and glob is not working.

I have saved four sound files into the directory specified, but when I try glob, I get nothing back.

ATTEMPT 1:

```php
$files = array();
foreach (glob($authorURL.'/'.$titleURL."*.wav") as $file) {
    $files[] = $file;
    echo $file;
}
```

ATTEMPT 2:

```php
$dir1 = $authorURL.'/'.$titleURL.'/'.$wordsURL;
$dir = glob("$dir1/*.{wav}");
$files = scandir($dir);
if(!empty($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $file) 
        print " <div class='fileicon'>
                    <audio controls='controls'> 
                        <source src='".$dir.$file."' />  
                    </audio> 
                    <button class='button' disabled>Reply</button>
                    </a>
                </div>";
    } 
else 
{
    echo "There are no annotations for this book"; 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm not sure if I'm using the right formatting for glob, but every time I search, it seems there are different versions ( `{}`, `""`).

Comment: 1. Why do you use a different path in the attempts? 2. What are the values of: `$authorURL`, `$titleURL`, `$wordsURL` ?

Comment: Also i can see `<a/>` closing tag, but nothing's opening it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong syntax for glob.  According to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), the syntax of glob when using curly braces (which signifies limited alteration) demands that you specify a special parameter

> glob also supports limited alternation with {n1, n2, etc..}.  You have
>   to specify GLOB_BRACE as the 2nd argument for glob in order for it to
>   work.  So for example, if you executed glob("{a,b,c}.php", GLOB_BRACE)
>   on the following list of files:
>
> a.php  b.php  c.php

Try executing it like this instead, either:

```
$dir = glob("$dir1/*.{wav}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

OR

```
$dir = glob("$dir1/*.wav");
```